# Having error during adding a search feature in my ecommerce Django website

Tags: python, django, search

I put this command to my powershell:

```
python manage.py startapp search
```

And I am getiing this error again again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\Django_Prac\Hello\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\Django_Prac\Hello\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'search'
```

**What can I do now? Please help!**

I want to know how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your new app to your new app to your registered apps:

settings.py file:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'search',
    # other apps
]
...
```